# Why does constructor property return entire block of class?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, constructor

Why does the constructor property of a class instance contain the entire body of a class, not just the constructor function?

```
// given: 
class C {
  constructor() {
    this.data = 'some data'
  }
  fn() {
    console.log('in fn')
  }
}
const c = new C()

c.__proto__.constructor
// returns
// class C {
//   constructor() {
//     this.data = 'some data'
//   }
//   fn() {
//     console.log('in fn')
//   }
// }

Object.getPrototypeOf(c).constructor
// returns
// class C {
//   constructor() {
//     this.data = 'some data'
//   }
//   fn() {
//     console.log('in fn')
//   }
// }

c.constructor
// returns 
// class C {
//   constructor() {
//     this.name = 'some data'
//   }
//   fn() {
//     console.log('in fn')
//   }
// }
```

I would think it would just return the actual constructor. As I understand, pre-ES2015, after extending a "class", a constructor would be reset to the child class's function body, eg:

```
function Parent() { console.log('function body parent') }
function Child() { console.log('function body child') }
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype); 
Child.prototype.constructor = Child; // reset
```

However, I'm a little confused here because trying to see the constructor here just gets me *`[native code]`*

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Child).constructor
ƒ Function() { [native code] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, in both cases `.constructor` just refers to the *constructor function*.

> Why does the constructor property of a class instance contain the entire body of a class, not just the constructor function?

The console tries to help you, if you tell it to log a *constructor function*, it will also show the methods of the prototype. (It will probably use some internal properties to determine wether the function was created with `class` or not and show the function differently based on that). If you call [`Function#toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) on *constructor functions* created with `class`you can observe the same behaviour.

> I'm a little confused here because trying to see the constructor here just gets me [native code]

`Object.getPrototypeOf(Child)` confuses you cause you called it on *the constructor function itself and not onto an instance*. And the * constructor function* inherits from `Function` directly, unless it is a subclass created with `class`, then there is some magic stuff going on that sets the *prototype* (not the `.prototype`property) of the * constructor function* to the *superclass constructor function* (to inherit static properties).

Comment: Thank you. _`Object.getPrototypeOf(Child)` confuses you cause you called it on the constructor function itself and not onto an instance._ If I understand correctly then, what I have done here is call the constructor function of the `Parent` class _as though_ it were a static method, eg `Parent.constructor()`. Is this correct?

Comment: Practically speaking, is the `.constructor` method used beyond what I use in my "pre-ES2015" example, when setting the constructor back to that of an extended child class after having set its prototype. I believe this is the only place I have seen it used.

Comment: No. With `getPrototypeOf(Child)` you haven't called anything except of `getPrototypeOf`.

Comment: The `.constructor`property can be used on/in instances to refer back to the function it was constructed from, otherwise there won't be any way to get back to the constructor from an instance

Comment: Ah, that first comment should actually have been `Object.getPrototypeOf(Child).constructor`, sorry was quoting, and forgot to add a step to explain the actual question